# Netsuite get salesorder and items based on job/project #

Tags: c#, netsuite

I trying to use C# in order to get a list of sales orders based on a job/project #.
Here is the code I am using:

```
TransactionSearchBasic tsb = new TransactionSearchBasic() {
mainLine = new SearchBooleanField() {
    searchValue = true,
    searchValueSpecified = true,
},
type = new SearchEnumMultiSelectField() {
    @operator = SearchEnumMultiSelectFieldOperator.anyOf,
    operatorSpecified = true,
    searchValue = new string[] { "_salesOrder" },    
}
};
SearchResult results = _service.search(tsb);
```

The code I have above gives a list of orders, 2 pages and 1000 results.
What do I need to do to filter this search based on job/project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those that are looking for an answer:

```
TransactionSearchBasic tsb = new TransactionSearchBasic() {
    mainLine = new SearchBooleanField() {
    searchValue = true,
    searchValueSpecified = true,
},
type = new SearchEnumMultiSelectField() {
    @operator = SearchEnumMultiSelectFieldOperator.anyOf,
    operatorSpecified = true,
    searchValue = new string[] { "_salesOrder" },    
},
.entity = new SearchEnumMultiSelectField() {
    @operator = SearchEnumMultiSelectFieldOperator.anyOf,
    operatorSpecified = true,
    searchValue = new RecordRef[] {New RecordRef {
                        type = RecordType.job,
                        name ="your job name"
 }}};
SearchResult results = _service.search(tsb);
```

Just enter the name of your job and this should return a "list" of salesOrders for that project.

Hope this helps anyone else needing to mess around with NETS*ite. :)